# Hi, I`ve got a problem with my course work, "return value ignored 'fscanf'":

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, scanf, return-value

i`ve got a problem with my course work, i need to find
The only problem is to scan input file, so the result become wrong.
How can I fix it and why?
"return value ignored 'fscanf'"

```
double E;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fscanf(inp_file, "%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &inp[i].T, &inp[i].delt, &inp[i].Tk0, &inp[i].m0, &inp[i].n, &inp[i].R0, &inp[i].h, &inp[i].delF);
```

Comment: `fscanf` returns a value for a reason. [Read the description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value). Ignoring it means you are not interested in whether it worked or not. Why call it in the first place then?

Answer (score 0):

Checking return values is crucial in C, and that what this warning is about.

`scanf` and it's similar functions returns the amount of successful assignments. If this is not equal to the number of variables you passed for assignment, that would mean that something is wrong.

So you should do something like this:

```
int n = fscanf(inp_file, "%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &inp[i].T, &inp[i].delt, &inp[i].Tk0, &inp[i].m0, &inp[i].n, &inp[i].R0, &inp[i].h, &inp[i].delF);

if(n != 8) {
    // Handle error
}
```